# "loading" image hangs when navigating to next page

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, iframe, loader

I have a webpage that proceeds (when user clicks 'Next') to a complex server-side operation. Internet Explorer sometimes gives the user the impression that nothing is happening at this stage, so I wanted to display a "loader" gif and the message "Please wait..." However, the loader gif e.g. [http://ajaxload.info](http://ajaxload.info/) stops spinning as soon as Internet Explorer changes its href location giving the users (who are "special") the impression that the website has "hung" and they close the page!

I thought an `<iframe>` element was what I needed to stop the spinning loader image from "hanging" but it isnt - does anyone have a clue what Im talking about and how I can achieve this?

Very confusing, thanks for your understanding :P

Comment: iFrame should not have anything to do with that. I've had the same experience — IE seems to stop animated GIFs sometimes in these kind of situation. I'd guess that there's not much you can do, but maybe someone proves me wrong.

Comment: Which version of IE?  Also, re-tag to include some variant of 'internet-explorer'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check [Animated GIF in IE stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping)