# jQuery - IE7 does not animate gif in modal dialogue

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an animated gif that lets the user know a page is loading.  The GIF does not animate in IE7.  After some troubleshooting I know the problem can be caused by

- Preload event loading images in
  body tag (not the case).
- An IE
  Setting in Tools > Internet Options >
  Advanced tab > Multimedia section >
  "Play animations in webpages*" should
  be checked.  It is checked

.

The GIF still does not animate.  I created a webpage.  
**This animates in IE7:**

```
<div>
    <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>
```

---

This does **not** animate in IE7

*jQuery*

```
                $('.searchButton').click(function () {
                    $("#divLineItemComments").dialog("open");
                });
```

*ASP.NET*

```
<asp:Button ID="searchBtn" Text="Search" class="search_btn searchButton" 
                                    runat="server" onclick="searchBtn_Click"  />

            <div id="divLineItemComments" style="display:none;clear:both;text-align:center;">
                <div>                    
                    <img src="images/ajax-loader.gif" alt="Loading..." />
                </div>
            </div>
```

*ASP.NET Code Beside*

```
protected void searchBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread.Sleep(2000);//simulate work
    Response.Redirect("Animate.aspx");//redirect back to current page to complete POST
}
```

---

Dropping the dialogue code out entirely and instead using div.Show() also fails

```
                $('.searchButton').click(function () {
                    $("#divLineItemComments").show();
                });
```

So this tells me the issue is most likely with jQuery.  The issue occurs in IE7, not firefox 4.  How can I fix it?  Maybe jQuery pre-loads images in the background...I dunno..?

Comment: I wrestled with something like this for a long time in IE7. Never solved it. Good luck.

Comment: Have you tried forcing the browser to hide the image itself and then show it?  This call would immediately proceed the " $("#divLineItemComments").show();" call. 
Maybe that will force the browser to redraw the image.

Comment: @jon_brockman - not quite sure what you mean.  I just tried letting the div be visible and then hiding it with div.hide() on document.ready.  This did not work.

Comment: I also found a potential solution on SO. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping.  But, this only works when I `return false;` from my javascript.  Pretty much blowing away the point of clicking submit (I need to POST)...

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing works.  I've tried multiple workarounds.  Similar questions on SO, the answers do not work if you need to POST.  I didn't notice at first, but IE just stops all the animations (including the one I said was working) when the POST begins.  Its impractical to convert everything to an ajax request.

I'm agreeing with AnthonyWJones on [Animated GIF in IE stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping) and going with

**Ø  no solution**

Answer (score 1):

Try forcing the browser to draw the image when you show its container div. Here you'll initially be writing a placeholder image in your div but will be swapping its source attribute using JS after clicking your search button.

```
<div id="imageContainer">
    <img id="loadingImage" src="images/clear.gif" alt="Loading..." />
</div>

$('.searchButton').click(function () {
  $('#loadingImage').attr('src','images/ajax-loader.gif');
});
```

Comment: This did not work either.  I believe the issue is that IE stops all animations once you begin a POST.  I put a link to a similar question on SO below my question.  Though, the answers do not work.

Comment: I think @AnthonyWJones is correct. @chrislegend  Nothing works.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping