# How to show a loading gif mean while a submit form is being executed JQuery

Tags: jquery, loading, form-submit

I'm trying to show a simple spinner gif meanwhile a submit is being executed (it takes a bit because I have to establish some communications with providers via web services).

So, I have this:

```
$('#gds_form').submit(function() {
        var pass = true;
        //some validations

        if(pass == false){
            return false;
        }

        $("body").prepend('<div class="ui-widget-overlay" style="z-index: 1001;"></div>');
        $("body").prepend("<div id ='PleaseWait'><img src='/images/spinner.gif'/></div>");
        return true;
    });
```

the thing is, that the .gif doesn't show any animation, it's like it is frozen.

Why?

There's another way to implement this (notice that I'm not using AJAX and I don't want to)?

Thank you.

Comment: i assume you are using an animated gif and that it animates if you show it "normally"

Comment: If the `gif` is frozen, that has nothing to do with JavaScript/jQuery.

Comment: **The gif is frozen cause IE6, IE7 and IE 8 are buggy.** Don't know about IE9 yet, but I know for sure **on all other browsers the gif does NOT freeze**. Read this for the [correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/780617/260080) and for [some possibile workarounds](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7151504/260080).

Comment: The gif freezes on my Ubuntu/Firefox but not on my Ubuntu/Chromium

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried loading the image on document ready, only having it hidden. Then display it in your function? This way, the image is already loaded and spinning.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").prepend('<div id="overlay" class="ui-widget-overlay" style="z-index: 1001; display: none;"></div>');
    $("body").prepend("<div id='PleaseWait' style='display: none;'><img src='/images/spinner.gif'/></div>");
});

$('#gds_form').submit(function() {
    var pass = true;
    //some validations

    if(pass == false){
        return false;
    }
    $("#overlay, #PleaseWait").show();

    return true;
});
```

Comment: Did this work??? In my tests the image continues to freeze under IE7 and IE8, on all other browser the image does NOT freeze until the server response arrives.

Comment: This does not work with my Ubuntu/Firefox (the gif animation freezes)

Answer (score 17):

Using the jQuery `submit` function, you can specify a loading image like this:

```
$('#form').submit(function() {
    $('#wait').show();
    $.post('/somepage.htm', function() {
        $('#wait').hide();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Using the show hide with the submit function worked well. Simple and robust.

Answer (score 2):

The real issue with your implementation is how does the client side know when your request has completed. One of the reasons why Ajax is helpful is because we have a notion of states and therefore we can display a loader while the client is waiting for a response and remove the loader when the client receives a response.

How are you going to determine when the communication with the web service is completed? You say that you don't want to use Ajax, but if you are going to want to query a service to determine whether your communication completed, you are probably seeing something that will require Ajax.

Comment: It's a regular form submit, when you click it the browser doesn't take you away until the server has responded to the request, giving animation time to spin a little. However, in IE (tested 7-9) starting the request will freeze the animation, even if it was already spinning on the page.

Answer (score 1):

Use .show() and .hide() to toggle the loading animation while it sends?

Answer (score 0):

I would the div on the page to start with, but with `style='display:none'` then stick a `$('#PleaseWait').show()` in your code when you want it to appear.

If you leave the `display:none` off you can edit see what it looks like without needing to submit the form again and again.

**NB:** you may want to wrap the overlay and the `gif` in a parent div for convenience.