# Progress Bar for Grails application

Tags: grails, progress

I am trying to use a progressbar for my grails application. I have a src/groovy/MyClass.groovy which does some function when called from a controller class called MyController. I need to show the progress of the work done by the MyClass.groovy on my MyWebpage.gsp when I click a submit button on the MyWebpage.gsp.

I referred to [this](http://grails.org/plugin/jprogress)  but what I am not understanding is this part of the code:

```
<g:form>
<g:submitToRemote action="executeAction"  name="progressButton" value="start...."/>
</g:form>
```

What is executeAction and progressButton in this?  There is not much information given on the documentation. Sorry for this basic question. Also, if anyone knows of a better approach to show the progress, please let me know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`executeAction` is the controller action which is called via ajax (see example action from the docs)

```
def executeAction = {

    for (int i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {

        //this updates the progress bar value for the progress id 123
        progressService.setProgressBarValue("123", i)

        //let's waste some time
        for (int a = 0; a < 10000; a++) {

            for (int b = 0; b < 1000; b++) {

            }
        }
    }

    render "the progress is done"
}
```

`progressButton` should be the name of the button, which is used later from the line `<g:jprogressDialog  progressId="123" trigger="progressButton"/>` to probably update the status bar on the client.

But as you are asking about an alternative, i would suggest, to use just plain jquery(-ui) for this. Combining something like [jquery-ui progressbar](http://api.jqueryui.com/progressbar/) with jquery ajax calls should to the trick. Examples of this is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9540957/jquery-ajax-loop-to-refresh-jqueryui-progressbar).

Comment: I am not making any AJAX calls. Honestly i have never worked with AJAX. Is there anything I could do to just show the progress bar after clicking submit and till the time another gsp is rendered?

Comment: `<g:submitToRemote action="executeAction"  name="progressButton" value="start...."/>` does exactly this - making a ajax call (perhaps without you knowing it (@see [docs](http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Tags/submitToRemote.html)). If you just want to a loading animation showing up until the http response from the form submit occurs, this could be achieved by listening to the form submit via js and then display a spinner: [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8140946/how-to-show-a-loading-gif-mean-while-a-submit-form-is-being-executed-jquery)