# IE8 stops the loading GIF image

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I'm calling an animated loading gif image on an `<asp:Button>` on client click.
But when the server-side code is running, the image stops animating in IE8.
It's working fine in Mozilla and other browsers.

This works when using a normal HTML button, but I need to use an ASP.NET Button.

my javascript code:

```
$("#movingimg1").css("display","block");
```

Comment: i have a asp button ,onclientclick event m calling a javascript fun,where m showing a loading gif.ok then it goes to its server side clik event in .cs page. during this the loading image stops in IE. r u getting my problem?

Comment: what are you doing in your javascript? Have you looked at using an `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: @user1058182 I've cleaned up you text as much as I could, but next time please put in more effort when asking a question. This isn't twitter/SMS so you don't need to abbreviate you text. Remember, you're asking others to spend their time helping you, so the least you can do is make it easier for them to understand your problem.

Comment: Thanks i will take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a known limitation of IE8.

What you'll need to do is pre-load the image with Javascript.

Comment: Even better, I found a dupe of your question on SO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping