# Animated GIF in IE 8 stopping

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, gif

I need to diplay a spin gif. I was following this link [Animated GIF in IE stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping)
and the solution given to break up your GIF to say 10 images. I tried that however its not giving me the right results either on IE8 or Chrome17.

Only half of the frames gets displayed on both IE8 and chrome. However when i right click on spinner image on IE8 it starts showing the image correctly till the time rightclick pop up is open on the image. Any help on this issue would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide your inputs on this issue. Would Appreciate a quick response

Answer (score 0):

Jquery:

```
$("#WhereYouWantTheImageToAppear").html('<img src="./Animated.gif" />');
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but the solution was in the browser settings:

Enabling Animation on Internet Explorer 8 or 9

Step 1: Launch Internet Explorer.

Step 2: Click the Gear (Settings) icon in the –top right corner of the window. It is located beside the Favorite icon and below X-button.

Step 3: Select Internet Options.

Step 4: Under Internet Options window, go to Advanced tab.

Step 5: Scroll down and find Play animations in webpages* under Multimedia.

Step 6: Put a check mark on it. Multimedia Setting options on Internet Explorer 9

Step 7: Click Apply then OK.

Step 8: Restart Internet Explorer.

Step 9: Drag a gif image file from your hard drive to Internet Explorer. The animation should now be working fine.

Note: This solution applies only when animation setting on IE9 is disabled which is the main cause for non-playing animated GIF files. If it doesn’t work, I advise you reset IE’s current settings to default and it might help as well (Internet Options – Advanced – Reset…). Do that if only if you made changes to IE’s settings before.