# how to stop progress gif image when processing is stopped in browser

Tags: javascript, html, progress-bar, loading

How can i stop "progress bar gif image" when i stopped processing by clicking "Stop Loading This Page" in web browser? When i clicked submit button then loading.gif image is displayed and now if i clicked to stop browser's stop button then also that loading.gif is still running, how can i stop it? Gif should be stopped when browser's stop is clicked but it is not stopping and continuing. How can i solve it?

//Here when submit button is clicked then loading.gif image is displayed

```
 <input onclick="showImg()" type="submit" name="submit" value="Search"/>

 <img alt="" src="loading.gif" id="progress_img" style="visibility:hidden;">

 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
 function showImg()
 {
 if (document.getElementById) { (document.getElementById("progress_img")).style.visibility = "visible"; }
 }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply hide the gif when the "stop" browser button is clicked.

```
document.onstop = function() {
     (document.getElementById("progress_img")).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
```

Comment: can you please add little bit more as i have written with in script tag , it is not working here

Comment: Here's a working example: http://help.dottoro.com/ljjvnosr.php (Note that this a sub-optimal solution because it works only in IE)

Answer (score 1):

The challenge is that most solution are browser specific ...

You can try different examples form

[Stopping GIF Animation Programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3688460/stopping-gif-animation-programmatically)

[Animated GIF in IE stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping)

It has been well discussed

Thanks

:)