# Background animation does not animate in Internet Explorer 9.0

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer-9

I am using Jquery to hide/show divs on form submit - to hide the form and to show a "loading..." text and animation. It works fine in all browsers except Internet Explorer (my version is 9.0). In Internet Explorer the background animation does not animate, it appears as a static gif. Any ideas how to solve this problem?

Background animation was generated @ http://www.ajaxload.info/ website

**script:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#enf").submit(function(){
        $('#formdiv').hide();
        $('#wait').show();    
    });
});
</script>
```

**form**

```
    <div id="formdiv">
    <form id="enf" name="enf" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/upload4.php" method="post">
        ......form elements.......
        <input type="submit" value="Send" name="add" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <div id="wait">Please wait...</div>
```

**css file:**

```
#wait{
    display:none;
    text-align:center;
    float:left;
    width:778px;
    background:#fdfdfd url('/loading.gif') no-repeat center center;padding:60px 0 20px 0;
}
```

Comment: I think name attribute of form is clashing with id attribute as both are same, can you rename your form name attribute and check,

Comment: I changed it but Internet Explorer still show animation as a static gif.

Comment: What happens when you open just the gif file in IE9, does it animate?

Comment: replace $('#formdiv').hide(); with this $(this).parent().hide();

Comment: Possible duplicate: [animated-gif-in-ie-stopping](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping) and [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/780617/206614).

Comment: When I open just a gif file in IE9, it does animate without any problems. I tried to replace $(this).parent().hide(); but it does not help.

Comment: I added gif to the container: <div id="wait"><img src="/loading.gif">Please wait...</div> but this does not help. It sows up as a static.

Comment: Did you read the answer I linked to? It says it's how IE works - it stops execution of GIF animations when you submit a form.

Comment: Yes, I read the answer and I tried solution from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping but it does not animate anyway :(

Comment: It looks that I have to leave it as it is. Always problems with Internet Explorer :(

Answer (score 3):

I know this is an old question, but I ran into the same problem today. Here's my solution to the CSS background specific image not animating (rather than an `img` tag). It works in IE8, IE9, and the latest versions of Firefox and Chrome.

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function () {
    var submitButton = $('input[type="submit"]');
    submitButton.button('enable');
    submitButton.after('<span class="spinner"></span>');
    submitButton.parents('form:first').submit(function () {
        submitButton.button('disable');
        window.setTimeout("ieSpinnerFix()", 25);
    });
});

function ieSpinnerFix() {
    $('.spinner').css('background', 'url(/Content/Common/Images/ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center left');
    $('.spinner').show();
    window.setTimeout("anyOtherFunctions()", 5000);
}

function anyOtherFunctions() {
    $('.spinner').text('We are processing your request, please stand by for awesomeness.');
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<form action="/Search" method="post">
    <div class="pageNav">
        <input type="submit" value="Search" />
    </div>
</form>
```

**CSS Styles:**

```
.spinner {
    display: none;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background: url('/Content/Common/Images/ajax-loader.gif') no-repeat center left;
    margin: auto 10px;
}
```

The idea is that the initial `setTimeout` allows the browser to calm down after submitting the form. I ran into strange issues with Chrome if the time out was too low. The reapplying of the background CSS to the is similar to the fixes for  tags that have been referenced in other posts.

Comment: answer still holds strong. i used it in a condition to fire only in IE `self.ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
    self.msie = self.ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
    self.isIE11 = self.ua.match(/Trident.*rv[ :]*11\./);if( self.msie > 0 || self.isIE11 )
            {
                self.ieProgressFix();
            } `