# display loading animation when user clicked on an element until page loads

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, animation, loading

I used the example from Jonathan from [How can I create a "Please Wait, Loading..." animation using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1964839/jquery-please-wait-loading-animation). I don't use AJAX calls. Instead I use this firing event:

```
$("body").addClass("loading");
$("#select-place input").click(function(){
    $("body").addClass("loading");
});
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    $("body").removeClass("loading"); 
});
```

With the first line I get the animated icon in FF24 when the user clicks on my input element. But in IE10 the icon doesn't spin. What I'm doing wrong? I tried to preload the image but that doesn't change anything.

**CSS:**

```
.modal {
    display:    none;
    position:   fixed;
    z-index:    1000;
    top:        0;
    left:       0;
    height:     100%;
    width:      100%;
    background-color: rgba( 255, 255, 255, .8 ) ;
    background-image: url(../images/design/loading.gif);
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    opacity: 0.80;
    -ms-filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity = 80);
    filter: alpha(opacity = 80)
}

/* When the body has the loading class, we turn
   the scrollbar off with overflow:hidden */
body.loading {
    overflow: hidden;   
}

/* Anytime the body has the loading class, our
   modal element will be visible */
body.loading .modal {
    display: block;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal"></div>
```

Why does the icon (gif) doesn't spin? I've tested all browser so far and it works except in IE...

Comment: Can we see your CSS please? You are adding a class to the body (odd) so the effect is presumably lower down the DOM hierarchy.

Comment: The HTML and the CSS are placed at the end of the documents. Should I change that? See my updated question for the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is described in [Animated GIF in IE stopping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping). The problem exists for IE in general (even IE10). The solution is to use [spin.js](http://fgnass.github.io/spin.js/). For the centering in the middle of the screen I used [this solution.](https://github.com/fgnass/spin.js/issues/17)

**HTML:**

```
<div id ="center" style="position:fixed;top:50%;left:50%"></div>
```

**JS:**

```
var opts = {
  lines: 13, // The number of lines to draw
  length: 8, // The length of each line
  width: 4, // The line thickness
  radius: 11, // The radius of the inner circle
  corners: 1, // Corner roundness (0..1)
  rotate: 0, // The rotation offset
  direction: 1, // 1: clockwise, -1: counterclockwise
  color: '#000', // #rgb or #rrggbb or array of colors
  speed: 1, // Rounds per second
  trail: 60, // Afterglow percentage
  shadow: false, // Whether to render a shadow
  hwaccel: false, // Whether to use hardware acceleration
  className: 'spinner', // The CSS class to assign to the spinner
  zIndex: 2e9, // The z-index (defaults to 2000000000)
  top: 'auto', // Top position relative to parent in px
  left: 'auto' // Left position relative to parent in px
};
var target = document.getElementById('center');
var spinner = new Spinner(opts);

$("#select-place input").click(function(){
    spinner.spin(target);
});
$(window).bind("load", function() {
    spinner.stop();
});
```