# Cannot get div element by id to display gif in internet explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, internet-explorer

I am trying to make a .gif image display in a loading window to alert my user that loading is underway, quite simple. I was doing it using only css and `background` property like this:

/*background: url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center #fff;*/

but my .gif was not loading in internet explorer. So I've made a research and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/780560/animated-gif-in-ie-stopping) and, based on J.Davies's solution, I have implemented this instead in my js file:

```
function ShowProgress() {
    if (!spinnerVisible) {
        $('div#layer').fadeIn("fast");
        $('div#spinner').fadeIn("fast");
        spinnerVisible = true;

        var pb = $('#spinner');
        pb.innerHTML = '<img src="./ajax-loader.gif" width=200 height=40/>';
        pb.style.display = "";
    }
}
```

My problem is that it works still in chrome, but I get a crash in internet explorer saying that it pb is undefined. Is there a specificity on how to work with jquery and internet explorer? For information, here's my display:

```
<div id="body">
    @RenderSection("featured", false)
    <section class="content-wrapper main-content clear-fix">
        <section>
            @Html.Partial("MessageDisplay")
        </section>
        <div id="layer"></div>
        <div id="spinner">
            Loading, please wait...
        </div> 
        @RenderBody()
    </section>
</div>
```

And the css saying that spinner and layer div are hidden:

```
div#spinner {
    display: none;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 40%;
    left: 45%;
    /*background: url(ajax-loader.gif) no-repeat center #fff;*/
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    font: normal 16px Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin-left: -50px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    z-index: 2;
    overflow: auto;
}

div#layer {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #a4a3a3;
    background-color: rgba(164, 163, 163, 0.5);
    z-index: 1;
    overflow: auto;
    -moz-opacity: 0.5
}
```

Comment: `pb` is a jQuery object. not a dom reference so there is no `innerHTML` or `style`

Comment: Oh ok! Is there a way that I could tune my code above to make it work? I've tried to use the `document.getElementByID` code line but I had the same result...

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pb` is a jQuery object. not a dom reference so there is no `innerHTML` or `style` properties in it. You need to use the utility methods provided by jQuery to set those

```
var pb = $('#spinner');
pb.html('<img src="./ajax-loader.gif" width=200 height=40/>').show();
```

In your case you can use [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) to set the `innerHTML` and [.show()](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to make it visible

Comment: This seems to work, however I am not sure of the result because the initial css is not anymore visible; all I see now is a grey, transparent square displaying my gif. Is that the effect wanted?

Comment: Initially I have a white square, in the top I had "Loading, please wait..." and right underneath it I had my gif "playing". I want to reproduce the same effect on Internet explorer, hence my question.

Comment: Almost there! If I'm using this line instead: `pb.append('<img src="../../Content/ajax-loader.gif" width=250 height=250/>').show();` I do see the gif and my layout, however I am still not seeing the original white background. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

Change this :

```
        var pb = $('#spinner');
        pb.innerHTML = '<img src="./ajax-loader.gif" width=200 height=40/>';
        pb.style.display = "";
```

with this :

```
    var pb = $('#spinner');
    pb.html('<img src="./ajax-loader.gif" width=200 height=40/>');
    pb.css({'display':''});
```

Plus I must add that something IE8 have issue with `fadeIn` / `fadeOut` so I would recommande if you still have a problem to try `.show()` / `hide()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I have accepted Arun's answer because it has helped me get to the solution. Based on his answer and my css, I have finally managed to make this jquery call:

```
function ShowProgress() {
    if (!spinnerVisible) {
        $('div#layer').fadeIn("fast");
        $('div#spinner').fadeIn("fast");
        spinnerVisible = true;

        var spinner = $('#spinner');

        spinner.append('<img src="../../Content/ajax-loader.gif" width="250" height="250"/>').css('background', '#fff').show();
    }
}
```

This keeps every css element originally present and plays my gif in both internet explorer and all other browsers. Thanks!