# Unable to set background-image property in "beforeunload" event

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, onbeforeunload

I'm trying to solve IE-problem of not animating a `.gif` image, when it is displayed in `beforeunload` or `unload` events. I step into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3812178/1469208), but found it not working, so I played a little bit with this code.

I have come with something like that:

```
var
    spinner = $('.spinner-large'),
    spinnerBackgroundImage = spinner.css('background-image');

console.log(spinnerBackgroundImage);
console.log($('.spinner-large').css('background-image'));

spinner.css('background-image', spinnerBackgroundImage);

console.log(spinner.css('background-image'));

spinner.show();
```

This is not working. Spinner is displayed, but there is no background image. And console contains:

```
backend-extra.js:97     url(http://127.0.0.1/images/spinner-large.gif)
backend-extra.js:98     url(http://127.0.0.1/images/spinner-large.gif)
backend-extra.js:102    none
```

What am I missing? Why I can't set entire `background-image` property value with jQuery?

Note, that I [don't want to set a path to image in `background-image` property](https://stackoverflow.com/q/512054/1469208), because I already *know*, [how I should do this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/512067/1469208). I'm asking: *Why `background-image` property value is reset to `none`, when I'm trying to change it with above method*?

*EDIT*: **Here is an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trejder/sygyeqts/) for above problem**. This seems to be 100% `beforeunload` event-related issue. When clicking button, the very same code works just fine, while when refreshing the page or navigating to any other URL, console have the same output like above -- property is **not** set.

Answer (score 3):

There should be quotes around the URL:

```
background-image: url("http(...)spinner-large.gif");
```

Invalid formatting is reason enough for it to turn into none. Otherwise it might be helpful to create a jsfiddle, codepen, something like that. It does not seem like obvious behavior.

Edit: this is beyond me, but it doesn't seem like your fault either. I'd suggest working around it. Possible even in an ugly way, like not animating the background on IE. (gracefully degrading should be okay anyway!)

Comment: I'll try to do a jsFiddle ASAP. Notice, that I'm **copying** value set by browser / CSS, never modified by me. So, missing (or not -- I don't know, if console _has it all_) quotes should not be the problem here.

Comment: Thing is, it may not want it written as it is read. But that is kind of perplexing me about this, too.

Comment: The quotes are optional.

Comment: In the documentation is says "When using .css() as a setter, jQuery modifies the element's style property.", which could be a hint. What does the style property look like afterward?

Comment: Also relevant:
"Warning: one notable exception is that, for IE 8 and below, removing a shorthand property such as border or background will remove that style entirely from the element, regardless of what is set in a stylesheet or <style> element."

Comment: @chipChocolate.py well there goes my cookie ;)

Comment: See my updated answer. Here is an [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/trejder/sygyeqts/) for this problem. This seems to be 100% `beforeunload` event-related issue.